# One of my Mongoid models has forgotten that is a database object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

So I have this model object `Shop::Order`, which has worked fine until now.
But today I get these weird errors in my forms `Undefined method 'model_name' for Shop::Order:Class`.

So I look around and test in my console, that all instances of `Shop::Order` don't have any persistence methods. But still my tests don't fail. So I load up the test console and there `Shop::Order` works perfectly.

This doesn't really make any sense to me and I'm quite frankly out of Ideas on how to solve this.

Here's a link to the model: [Shop::Order](https://github.com/deiga/new-Roydon/blob/feature/allow-orders-without-registeration/app/models/shop/order.rb?source=c)

The error appears in this view: [new.html.haml](https://github.com/deiga/new-Roydon/blob/feature/allow-orders-without-registeration/app/views/shop/orders/new.html.haml?source=c#L18)

All other models are working totally fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lays in [config/initializers/contants.rb](https://github.com/deiga/new-Roydon/blob/feature/allow-orders-without-registeration/config/initializers/contants.rb#L3) where you're predefining your `Shop::Order` class.

I assume what happens is, the autoloader does not search further once it already has the class defined.

You should remove it, as this is not the `initializer` use case to define model's constants.